# DisplayLink vs Plugable vs Generic USB-VGA adaptor Performance

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors, adapter, displaylink

I am a new owner of Dell 7567 and planned to connect two external monitors to it, but unfortunately, the manufacturer only provided one HDMI port.

So I google about it, and just found out that there exists an [USB-VGA](https://www.ebay.com/bhp/usb-to-vga-adapter) adaptor, so bought I it and tried it.  With a bit of hassle, I can get it to work, but it has a slight delay input also has a huge performance impact.

I have 2 monitors, monitor A plugged to HDMI, monitor B plugged to USB-VGA adaptor, if there is nothing moving (video etc) played on monitor B, it works perfectly, I can play game on monitor A with solid 60 fps, but when there is something moving on monitor B (youtube), my game on monitor A dip into 40 fps

I stumbled upon Dell docking station with DisplayLink tech in it [Dell Docking Station](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-docking-station-usb-30-d3100/apd/452-bbpg/pc-accessories), and I also found [Plugable USB-Display Adaptor](https://plugable.com/products/usb3-hdmi-dvi/), so my question is, how much of the overhead the DisplayLink and Pluggable cause ?, which one is better?, and is it even better than my "cheap" (can't really say its cheap) alternative generic USB-VGA adaptor that bought?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking the reason the manufacturer used DisplayPort instead of HDMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so today i push my luck and just bought Wavlink docking station with DisplayLink technology,this also applicable to Plugable since apparently they also use DisplayLink technology, and so far i'm honestly suprise how much better it is with my generic USB3.0-VGA adaptor (it use Fresco Logic driver)

theres lot of trial and error, disabling, enabling and uninstalling various display driver, if i type everything it'll be too long

but the point is, Display Link overhead is not much bigger than Fresco Logic, at maximum that i can see both of them utilize max only 5% of the cpu process

but even so, Display Link can detect my Nvidia GPU (i assume) since after i disabling my intel display driver, it run as smooth as it possibly can without any effect on the game, meanwhile Fresco Logic driver still run with intel basic display driver (i think) - theres no real proof for this unfortunately

but in short, with the same configuration, DisplayLink tech allow me to use dual monitor setup while have little to no effect to game, i can run FO4 on solid 60fps, while Fresco Logic, whatver i did even with same exact configuration, always dip to 40fps